# How to assign costs to the confusion matrix

Tags: r, machine-learning, classification, confusion-matrix

I am trying to assign costs to the confusion matrix. That is, in my problem, a false positive (FP) does not have the same cost as a false negative (FN), so I want to assign to these cases a cost "x" so that the algorithm learns based on those costs.

I will explain my case a little more with an example:

- When we want to detect credit card fraud, it does not have the same
  cost to predict that it is not fraud when in fact it is than the
  other way around. In the first case, the cost would be much higher.

What I wanted to know is if there is a library in R in which I can assign costs to these wrong decisions (i.e. give a cost to each possible value of the confusion matrix) or if there is an algorithm that learns based on a cost/benefit matrix.

I could also use some way to implement this without the use of a library.

Comment: Can you elaborate what "FP"  and "FN refer to?